# Insert Image Directory Into Database

Tags: java, sql

Why can't i insert a image directory properly into my tables?

```
Image Directory = C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\images\lampchop.jpg
Database Captured = C:UsersASUSDocumentsimageslampchop.jpg
```

It did successfully insert the image directory into my tables. However it only store the string without the `\` thus i cant retrieve images.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which code are you using to insert the value?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape the backslashes in order for the database to decode them. Without them, the database is considering the following characters to the backslashes as being escaped.

Just make it like:

```
Image Directory = C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Documents\\images\\lampchop.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `"\"` use `"\\"` or `"/"`

```
Image Directory = C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/images/lampchop.jp
```

or

```
Image Directory = C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Documents\\images\\lampchop.jpg
```